# how to determine the figure size of an open figure using the gui tool?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Lets say I am plotting a pandas.DataFrame

```
df.plot(figsize = (10,10))
```

I usually start with the default figure size and adjust the figure size using the gui tool to achieve the format I want (making sure all legends look ok etc). However for the next plot, I don't want to repeat the same process. I would like to get the proper size and next time just call the plot with the hard-coded figure size that I got from tinkering with gui tool. Is there a way to get the current figure size from the gui?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a reference to the plot axes:

```
ax = df.plot(figsize = (10,10))
```

You can then get the figure size later on using:

```
ax.get_figure().get_size_inches()
```